# Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, jquery-select2

I am having an angular JS application. In this I have a dropdown in which I can create a new option by typing and pressing enter key. However when I press enter key I get some JS exceptions

Here is the exception

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined
at angular.js:26183
at forEach (angular.js:336)
at readNgOptionsMultiple [as readValue] (angular.js:26181)
at angular.js:28062
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15830)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15929)
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:28061)
at HTMLSelectElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery-2.1.4.js:4435)
at HTMLSelectElement.elemData.handle (jquery-2.1.4.js:4121)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery-2.1.4.js:4350)
```

The file is Angular.js file and below is the location where it causes.

```
 forEach(selectedValues, function(value) {
        var option = options.selectValueMap[value];
        if (!option.disabled) selections.push(options.getViewValueFromOption(option));
      });
```

My HTML/Angular Code is as below

```
 <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
                                <select class="js-select2-tags form-control input-lg form-control-static" id="new-note-tags" name="note-tags" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Type one or more tags..."
                                        ng-model="addNote.AssociatedTags" ng-options="option.Name for option in NoteTags track by option.Name"
                                        data-rule-required="true"
                                        data-msg="Note tags cannot be empty"></select>
                                <label for="new-note-tags">Note Tags<span class="required"> * </span></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Could any one guide me here?

Update:
I hve checked this and my observation is the newly added option is actually not getting added into the options. 
var option = options.selectValueMap[value];

I have added this code to make sure options are added. Looks like it is not working. Please note I have a multi select control.

```
$('.js-select2-tags', $container).select2({
        tags: true,
        multiple: true,
        placeholder: jQuery(this).data('placeholder'),
        allowClear: false
    })

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say probably because your new option doesn't have value so the options.selectValueMap doesn't work as expected.

It returns undefined

Just test with

```
if(option && !option.disabled)
```

Comment: Looks like it is working but is it advisable to modify the angular.js file? Am new in this space and am not sure about the risk of changing the angular.js file

Comment: Probably not when you create your option, set a dummy value with some kind of counter which generate values like "new1", "new2" so you won't have a problem